# nginx не видит новый домен

Tags: linux, nginx

есть 2 версии проекта: dev и prod. для них организовано 4 конфига nginx: backend-dev, frontend-dev, backend-prod, backend-prod.

dev конфиги ссылаются на dev папку, prod - на prod.

проблема в том, что dev домен почему-то ссылается на prod.

т.е. при переходе на backend-dev меня кидает на backend-prod, и при переходе на frontend-dev меня так же кидает на backend-prod.

конфиги везде одинаковые, за исключением рута и логов, однако разделение prod работает нормально. значит дело не в схеме создание конфигов.

как исправить?

Comment: @nörbörnën, мне не нужны настройки, мне нужно чтобы кто-то, кто сталкивался с подобным, указал причину такого поведения nginx. если бы мне нужны были настройки, то я бы выложил конфиги.

Comment: то есть конфигурация nginx тут не при чём?

Comment: вангую: default_server? забыли перегрузить? те конфиги? тот сервер? логическая ошибка? промежуточный прокси? редирект апача?

Comment: «dev конфиги ссылаются на dev папку, prod - на prod» — мы вам не очень хотим верить на слово, покажите что-нибудь, что подтвердит это утверждение. То же самое с «конфиги везде одинаковые» и «дело не в схеме» — вполне могла оказаться опечатка, которую вы не заметили, а мы заметим, так что покажите это всё. Или, возможно, конфиги *слишком* одинаковые, и помимо «рута и логов» нужно отредактировать что-то ещё (тот же навангованный default_server, например)

Answer (score 1):

Мой опыт администрирования линуха подсказывает, что причины обычно две:

1. Скопипастили конфиг и забыли в новом поменять хост
2. Забыли перезапустить nginx и он кидает на первый хост в списке (prod на "p" "выше" в списке, чем test на "t" в алфавитном порядке) при отсутствующем `default_server`

Вангую, что у Вас всё корректно и nginx перезапущен. В таком случае на что стоит обратить внимание - редиректы с `http` на `https`, первое. Второе - что везде указаны директивы `listen`, и в этом случае попробуйте поиграться с `default_server` - куда будет смотреть прод, если дефолт-сервером сделать тест? И по результату копать дальше.